# Dual boot Ubuntu MATE and Mac WITHOUT using rEFIt or rEFInd

Tags: boot, dual-boot, macosx, macbook-pro, ubuntu-mate

I wanted to try Ubuntu MATE on my MacBook Pro (2015 w/ macOS Sierra) but I **don't** want to use rEFIt or rEFInd.

Can I achieve this by simply creating a partition and install Ubuntu MATE onto it? Will the option show up when I hold the option key on startup?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can!

I have an unconventional installation with 3 partitions containing two Yosemite-10.10 and RecoveryHD on an external USB drive; it boots without trouble.

Since at boot time MacBios sees ALL bootable partitions present, putting another bootable partition on a HDD is similar to external USB.

Have a look at [Macbook revival playground](https://sourceforge.net/projects/toysbox/files/MacBook_revival_Playground/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a bit more work than just creating a boot partition, but you do not have to use rEFIt or rEFInd.
There is an excellent PDF guide for how to do this: http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs171/materials/pdfs/How_to_Dual-Boot_OSX_and_Ubuntu.pdf

I used this guide recently and it worked quite well. I did not install MATE, but the process should work equally well for any flavor of Ubuntu. I modified the instructions slightly because I installed on an external drive. In a nutshell, this is the process described in the guide:

1. Create the bootable live CD/DVD/USB; if you don't know already how to do this, you can use the instructions in the guide or download the "Mac Linux USB Loader," which works really well for Ubuntu. **Note:** If you use the method outlined in the doc, add a buffer block to the command or it will take *forever*!: The command suggested is this: `sudo dd if=/path/to/image.dmg of=/dev/rdiskN`. You will want to add `bs=1m`.
2. Create a boot loader partition from within OS X - it will be OS X Extended (Journaled) so that it will appear as an EFI partition, visible when you use the Option key at boot.
3. Install Ubuntu; this guide has a pretty good summary of how to do the install in a safe way so as not to risk ruining your OS X installation.
4. Create a grub config file that your boot loader will use.
5. Back in OS X, configure the boot loader partition so the Macbook will know it's a proper boot partition.  This step in the doc also includes info on how to make either OS X or Ubuntu the default OS to boot into. I have mine set up so that it boots into Ubuntu without using the option key, and I only use the option key if I want to boot back into OS X.